# Calling a class within the same class

Tags: php, class

Okay, this question may kind of weird or pointless but it's something I believe should be able to work in my toe of situation. So basically, I have a class called `Item`. In this class is a construct method that gets the item from my database and creates a object for that item and returns that object. But there is also another function called `give`. In this method, I give an item with the ID of the item to the user. But in every table of a item there is a field called `type` and to insert this into a users inventory there is also a field called `type`. I want to know if I'm able to call the class `Item` to a new variable, `$temp`, and use that to get the `type` field of that specific item. Here's my code:

```
class Item{
    public $i;

    public function __construct($itemid){
        if($this->checkItem($itemid)){
            $getItem = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id` = '$itemid'");
            $this->i = mysql_fetch_assoc($getItem);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function give($amount = 1, $itemid = null, $userid = null){
            if(!ctype_digit($amount)){
            return false;
            }
            if($amount < 0){
                return false;
            }
            if(is_null($itemid)){
                $itemid = $this->i['id'];
            }else{
            if(!$this->checkItem($itemid)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        $u = new User($userid);
        if($this->inInv($itemid, $userid)){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `inventory` SET `amount` = `amount` + {$amount} WHERE `id` = '{$this->inv['id']}'");
        }else{
            $temp = new Item($itemid);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `inventory` (`userid`, `itemid`, `amount`, `type`) VALUES ('{$u->u['userid']}', '{$itemid}', '$amount', '{$temp->i['type']}')");
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I don't use `$i` is because the item I want to give could be different than the item I already used to call the class.

Comment: Could you hightlight your question? And tell use what is wrong with this code?

Comment: from a design point of view, why does `give` have an `itemid`? If you want to give a different item then the one set, you're not using the right object (don't confuse class with object).